# Is it really that readline does not block on an empty file as it does on an empty file-like object?

Tags: python, readline, eof

Here is the code that I used to experiment with Python `readline()`.

```
import threading, os, time

def worker():
    file.seek(0) 
    print ("First  attempt on file: " +  file.readline().strip())
    print ("First  attempt on pipe: " +  Iget.readline().strip())
    print ("Second attempt on pipe: " +  Iget.readline().strip())
    file.seek(0) 
    print ("Second attempt on file: " +  file.readline().strip())
    print ("Third  attempt on file: " +  file.readline().strip())

fdIget, fdIset = os.pipe()
Iget = os.fdopen(fdIget)
Iset = os.fdopen(fdIset, 'w')

file = open("Test.txt", "w+")

t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
t.start()

time.sleep(2)
Iset.write("Parent pipe\n")
Iset.flush()
file.write("Parent file.\n")
file.flush()

time.sleep(2)
Iset.write("Again Parent pipe\n")
Iset.flush()
file.write("Again Parent file.\n")
file.flush()

t.join()
```

The output is

```
First  attempt on file: 
First  attempt on pipe: Parent pipe
Second attempt on pipe: Again Parent pipe
Second attempt on file: Parent file.
Third  attempt on file: Again Parent file.
```

It seems that `readline()` does not block on an empty file - perhaps it sees an EOF because the file is empty. On the other hand, `readline()` blocks on an empty file-like object - no EOF is seen until after we close the file-like object. I am expecting that I got it wrong - that I am missing something basic. It would have been more uniform to have `readline()` blocks on an empty file until after the handle is closed, as it does with a file-like object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File objects don't know if anyone else has an open handle to the file, so there is no way for them to distinguish "empty file with writers" from "empty file without writers"; a writer closing the file is not visible to the handle reading it.

By contrast, pipes communicate that sort of information, they're streams that are explicitly closed by the writer to communicate data to the reader.

If files acted like pipes, given the lack of info on writers, you'd block indefinitely when you ran out of lines, waiting for another line that would never arrive.

Basically, they're for fundamentally different purposes, don't expect one to behave exactly like the other.

Comment: I accept your answer because it answers the question. You say "Yes", a reader never blocks on an empty file. As far as what is the purpose of a file, I don't think anyone can decide that for another. There would be nothing wrong if an OS implemented a mutex internally to let the reader know if there are other handles (in a given category) on a file. The reader could block in those cases, even if it is empty. We could block for ever in some scenario, but this is also true with a pipe. If I create a file in my own directory, I can create a context where I would not block for ever, easily.

Comment: @Dominic108: In general, files are not intended or used for this purpose. Adding overhead to *every* file use to support a rare scenario (and one which can be handled in other ways when needed) is a terrible idea. Remember, the vast majority of programs open files only for reading (remember, a Python program typically opens dozens, if not hundreds, of DLLs/shared objects and modules before the main method even gets invoked). If every one of those involved more overhead just to verify "nope, no one is currently writing this so we're done", you're optimizing for the rare case.

Comment: It took me a while to understand the issue.  It is something basic, but not so obvious. If the reader is willing to loop querying the OS, then he may as well loop querying the file. So, the reader needs something that can block such as a mutex. It could be done at the Python level. Files that need to be managed as blocking streams could be separated. The application that owns the file would  decide if it is to be managed as a stream. This would be transparent to other Python applications. My point is that I don't see that it's necessarily a bad design that files can be blocking when empty.